# What structure does "We're having relatives to stay" follow?

Tags: grammar

I thought the structure was "have someone do something". So why is it "having relatives to stay" in this case?

Answer (score 1):

When you use "have + object + bare infinitive" construction, its meaning is close to "make + object + bare infinitive". In other words, it means "you ask or tell someone (the object of the transitive verb) to do something". For example,

> I'll have her call you tomorrow.

means

> I will ask / tell her to call you tomorrow.

Your example sentence uses a different construction. It means:

> We are having relatives (We will have relatives) **who will** stay.

To infinitive is broadly used to make a relative clause (your example) or [wh-clause](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/clause-phrase-and-sentence/verb-patterns/wh-clauses) shorter when the subject of those clauses are same as the subject or object of the main clause. In your example, the subject of to "stay" is the object of the main clause, which is "relatives".

You could also say "to infinitive" in your sentence is post-modifying the noun (relatives) in the same way as the relative clause is post-modifying the noun.

You can Google "to infinitive" to learn more about how it works.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning is that they are having relatives stay with them in their home for some unspecified period of time. They are doing something (the relatives); they are being house guests. Perhaps the confusion is in the "having relatives to stay" portion, which might be reworded to be "we will be hosting our relatives."